# mariaDB - error granting rights to users

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-grant

I have the following users in my database:

```
MariaDB [racktables]> select user from mysql.user;
+----------+
| user     |
+----------+
| admin    |
| rackuser |
| repluser |
| root     |
| root     |
| root     |
|          |
| admin    |
| rackuser |
| root     |
|          |
| root     |
+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to set up permissions but I keep getting the following error message:

```
MariaDB [racktables]> grant all on racktables.* to rackuser;
ERROR 1133 (42000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
MariaDB [racktables]>
```

The user clearly exists... I'm not sure why I'm getting this message. Unless.. this is my first crack at using mariaDB.  I've imported a mysql database into mariaDB.  And I'm assuming that mariaDB's users should be in the mysql.users table. 
But maybe I'm wrong?  I'm currently reading the mariaDB docs.. but I haven't found my answer yet. 
Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i just tried FLUSH PRIVILEGES ... and it's happier.  have to test to make sure it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run the

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

command first... and then the grants worked.